# need help. python integers and strings

Tags: python, string, integer

I have been having some issues with a line of code in a program I'm making. when ever I run the file it displays this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Main\Google Drive\computerprograming\mathoperationscalc.py", line 9, in <module>
    print('the sum of ' + x + ' and ' + y + ' is ')
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

Here is the code:

```
print('please input 1st integer')
x = input()
x = int(x)
print('please input 2nd integer')
y = input()
y = int(y)

Sum = x + y
print('the sum of ' + x + ' and ' + y + ' is ')
print(Sum)
```

Comment: (Or any of the 650 other SO questions you'd get if you'd bothered to Google the error message.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the `int` to `str` you so you can concatenate.

```
x = int(input('please input 1st integer'))
y = int(input('please input 2nd integer'))

total = x + y
print('the sum of ' + str(x) + ' and ' + str(y) + ' is ')
print(Sum)
```

Or use `format`

```
'the sum of {} and {} is {}'.format(x,y,total)
```